# React doesn't re-render component with new props when state changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to reuse a page that's already working in another page, and display it on the right side when the user clicks an item. Using the code below, the product's name shows up correctly on clicks, but the ItemDisplayPage only renders on the first click, and doesn't update on further clicks. I have tried using it as a UseState, UseRef, updating in UseEffect, in the handler, nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  const [auctionClicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  const [displayedItem, setDisplayed] = useState({} as AuctionItem);

  const [displayPage, setDisplayPage] = useState(<Col></Col>);

  let content = useRef(
.
.
  );
.
.
.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auctionClicked) {
      setDisplayPage(<Col>{displayedItem.product.name}<ItemDisplayPage auction={displayedItem} /></Col>);
    }
  }, [displayedItem]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [displayPage])

  const handleClick = (item: AuctionItem) => {
    setClicked(true);
    setDisplayed(item);
  };

  content.current = (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        {left.current}
        {displayPage}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );

  return content.current;
```

[The problem visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci53W.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't use the React Component as a state. You can use the string instead of it.

My idea is

```
const [displayPage, setDisplayPage] = useState('initial');
```

Then get needed component by name

```
return <Container>
      <Row>
        {getContentByName(displayPage)}
      </Row>
    </Container>
```

Comment: In this case, how can I pass the displayed item to the page? And is the getContentByName a provided function, or something i have to make myself?

Comment: getContentByName is a function that get displayPage and by using switch case return the right component. You have to make it yourself

Comment: I modified my code like this, and it still doesn't work:
`const getDisplayPage = () => {
    if(auctionClicked) { return <Col><ItemDisplayPage auction={displayedItem}/></Col> } else { return <Col></Col> } }`
And then i return:                                                                        
`content.current = (<Container><Row>{left.current}{getDisplayPage()}</Row</Container>);
`